# Why is the SpaceShipTwo being released from 44,300 ft, not from 50,000 ft as originally anticipated?

Tags: virgin-galactic, spaceplane

The VSS Unity is always released at an altitude of 44,300 ft (13.5 km) from the VMS Eve. The SpaceShipTwo was originally anticipated to be released at 50,000 ft (15.2 km) and many media still report something like "the WhiteKnightTwo is going to carry Unity to 50,000 ft where it will be released and start flying on its own" when in fact, Unity is always launching from 44,300 ft altitude.

Have there been any changes following the VSS Enterprise crash that no longer allow the spaceplane to be released higher than 45,000 ft? According to [the WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaled_Composites_White_Knight_Two), the WK2 has a service ceiling of 70,000 ft (21.3 km). If the SS2 were released near that altitude, shouldn't it be able to reach an apogee over 95 km?

Comment: I suspect that it might be due to the fact that SpaceshipTwo is initially a glider when it is released from White Knight Two. It then ignites its rocket motor to begin powered flight through the atmosphere,  quickly going into a sharp pull up to near vertical. It's possible that SpaceShioTwo needs more air density to safely perform these maneuvers than is available above 45,000 feet.

Comment: "*Unity is always launching from 44,300 ft altitude*" versus "*...that no longer allow the spaceplane to be...*". Please clarify if the spaceship was ever released at 50,000ft. If never, then 50,000 versus 44300 is just padding provided by marketing team to advertise a round number.

Comment: @AJN Both VSS Enterprise and Unity were released from or carried to 50 kft and higher during glide flights and captive carry flights as [shown here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Virgin_Galactic_launches). And rounding the wrong way for marketing purposes would be lying as it's quite a difference between the two numbers.

Comment: @StevePemberton But they initially anticipated to release it from 50,000 ft and did so a couple of times. So the question is why they release them from a lower altitude now, despite a different announcement in the past.

Comment: @Hannes - at 50,000+ feet they only glided. During powered flight they not only glided they pulled out of the descent, pulled up into a climb, and continued pitching up to near vertical. Quite a difference in flight dynamics between the two types of flight profiles. Possibly the more demanding maneuvers performed during the powered flights requires denser air. That could be something they determined during flight testing, which could explain the discrepancy with previously stated flight profiles